# Failure in Excluding values that are smaller than 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have a database which contains data abut plants and indices that were computed.
I am trying to exclude values that are smaller than 0 but for some reason I keep get negative numbers.

I have used this code:

```
df_indices=df_indices[(df_indices['YU_index'] > 0) |(df_indices['Zhao 405-715'] > 0)]
df_indices
```

but I still get negative numbers:

[image]

I have also gotten values smaller than 0 in "Zhao" but you can't see it here.

Edit: still getting less than 0 after using &:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
df_indices=df_indices[(df_indices['YU_index'] > 0) & (df_indices['Zhao 405-715'] > 0)]
```

Or:

```
df_indices=df_indices[(df_indices[['YU_index', 'Zhao 405-715']] > 0).all(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df_indices.query('YU_index > 0 and `Zhao 405-715` > 0', inplace=True)
```

which is more memory-efficient than df[df[]] filtering.

Comment: iwill this prevent the need to add .copy() in the end?

Comment: `which is more memory-efficient than df[df[]] filtering` - I always think it is not True, can you give me some link to docs for this? Or is possible add some test?

Comment: It's not easy to assess, but df[df[]] does use intermediate tables in the memory, while query won't do it. I personally on several occasions stumbled upon MemoryError with especially big table manipulation in a standard pandas way, while query worked fine.

Further reading
https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.12-performance-eval-and-query.html